# discretise domain of x and y with 0.01 separation between points

Tags: matlab, discretization

I am looking to calculate an array from a formula using x and y variables, the domain of x is (0,50) and y is (0,30) .  I am asked to discretise the domain of x and y with 0.01 separation between points, then compute L(x,y) (which I have a formula for)(This will be points of a graph, ultimately I'm looking for the min lengths between points)

I'm not sure what I need to define in my script because if I define x and y as arrays with 0.01 separation they end up being uneven and unable to calculate as the arrays are uneven

```
%change these values for A, B and C positions
Ax=10;
Ay=5;

Bx=15;
By=25;

Cx=40;
Cy=10;


x = 0:0.01:50; % Array of values for x from 0-50 spaced at 0.01
y = 0:0.01:30; % Array of values for y from 0-30 spaced at 0.01


%length of point P from A, B and C and display
Lpa=sqrt((Ax-x).^2+(Ay-y).^2);
Lpb=sqrt((Bx-x).^2+(By-y).^2);
Lpc=sqrt((Cx-x).^2+(Cy-y).^2);

L=Lpa+Lpb+Lpc
```

I am getting an error telling me the two matrix are not even which makes sense to not work but I'm not sure how to define a matrix that will result in the minimum x and y values I am after.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You want to calculate `L` for each possible pair of `x` and `y`. In other words, for the first value of `x = 0`, you will calculate `L` for all `y` values from 0 to 30, then for next value of `x = 0.01`, you will do the same and so on.

MATLAB has a really cool function called [meshgrid](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) to create a matrix for every pair of `x` and `y`. So after generating `x` and `y`, change your code to the following to get a 2D matrix for `L` -

```
[X, Y] = meshgrid(x, y)

%length of point P from A, B and C and display
Lpa = sqrt((Ax - X).^2 + (Ay - Y).^2);
Lpb = sqrt((Bx - X).^2 + (By - Y).^2);
Lpc = sqrt((Cx - X).^2 + (Cy - Y).^2);

L = Lpa + Lpb + Lpc
```

Comment: You guys are the greatest!  I got a one line answer from my tutor for this!  And she gets paid!!

Anyway!

So if I am understanding correctly I can set 

    x=linspace (0,50,3001); % Array of values for x from 0-50
    y = 0:0.01:30; % Array of values for y from 0-30 spaced at 0.01

and this will calculate correctly? ( I am not infront of matlab right now)

Comment: yes, it will if that's what you want. However your question asked for both `x` and `y` to have a spacing of 0.01, and your solution would not satisfy that for `x`.

Comment: So how would I go about satisfying it for x as well?  If spaced evenly it just won't work as the two arrays will be different sized

Comment: In the solution I proposed, the matrices are all the same size.

Comment: after looking at your answer more closely I see that, sorry!   Thankyou!